# req.handle.writev is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using React, React-Redux with Webpack for my project in a Docker container and keep running into this error

> internal/stream_base_commons.js:59   var err = req.handle.writev(req,
>   chunks, allBuffers);
>                          ^
>
> TypeError: req.handle.writev is not a function
>       at writevGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:59:24)
>       at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:758:5)
>       at Socket._writev (net.js:767:8)
>       at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:408:12)
>       at clearBuffer (_stream_writable.js:517:5)
>       at Socket.Writable.uncork (_stream_writable.js:314:7)
>       at connectionCorkNT (_http_outgoing.js:646:8)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)

The following is my versions

1. NODE_VERSION    8.9
2. YARN_VERSION    1.7.0
3. OS Docker Linux/ Raspbian Lite
4. Webpack/ Webpack-Ddv-Server (latest)
5. React/ Redux (latest)

My package.json

```
{
  ....
  "dependencies": {
    "object-assign": "*",
    "raf": "*",
    "react": "*",
    "react-dev-utils": "*",
    "react-dom": "*",
    "react-facebook-login": "*",
    "react-helmet": "*",
    "react-loadable": "*",
    "react-slick": "*",
    "react-router": "*",
    "react-router-dom": "*",
    "react-redux":"*",
    "redux":"*",
    "redux-thunk":"*",
    "slick-carousel":"*",
    "font-awesome":"*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "*",
    "npm-run-all": "*",
    "sass-loader": "*",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "resolve": "1.6.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack": "*",
    "webpack-dev-server": "*",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "*",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "*",
    "fs-extra": "*",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "*",
    "jest": "20.0.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start-js": "node scripts/start.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "node scripts/build.js",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "postinstall": "npm run start"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  }
}
```

Anyone else with this issue? Does not happen often but does frustrate the development process

Comment: perhaps https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21665 ?

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this error on Windows 10 x64 on NodeJS version 10.13.0. I simply removed NodeJS version 10.13.0 and installed version 8.11.3 and restarted my machine and it was gone!

Answer (score 3):

Anyone else with this issue? Yes...This problem is happening a lot with me and it is making me nervous, but usually, when it is happening I restart my computer and its gone!

For now, I think restarting the computer is the solution because I have searched too much for a solution, but I got zero results.

Comment: There has since been some updates and from what I had gathered it had a lot to do with using https. Update your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Delete node and do yarn install